# Moment JS diff() returns 0 days between Oct 31 and 1 Nov

Tags: momentjs

As is shown below `moment.diff()` incorrectly calculates `0` days between yesterday (31 October) and today (1 November). Is this a problem with [momentJS](https://momentjs.com/) or with NodeJS (v14.15.4)?

```js
> a = moment(new Date('2021-10-31'))
Moment<2021-10-31T02:00:00+02:00>
> b = moment(new Date('2021-11-01'))
Moment<2021-11-01T01:00:00+01:00>
> a.diff(b, 'days')
0
> a.diff(b, 'hours')
-24
```

One possible cause could be the summer => winter change that officially happened from Sun 31 Oct to Mon 1 Nov`*`. This is evident from the parsing of '2021-10-31' to a summer time `Moment<2021-10-31T02:00:00+02:00>` (2h).

Nevertheless, I would argue 24 hours diff should not come out as 0 days and thus it's a bug in Moment.

`*` Though everyone actually sets their clocks back on Sunday 31 Oct... go figure.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because there was the change of hour and that in `.diff()` for get the hour it's return a number lower than 1 and moment rounded it at 0.

You can change your code in that without use Date in the moment declaration:

```js
const a = moment('2021-10-31');
const b = moment('2021-11-01');

console.log(a.diff(b, 'days')); // -1
console.log(a.diff(b, 'hours')); // -25 <- but this is wrong
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Or in alternative you can force that `.diff()` function returns a floating instead of integer putting the third parameter, and after round it like that:

```js
const a = moment(new Date('2021-10-31'));
const b = moment(new Date('2021-11-01'));

console.log(Math.round(a.diff(b, 'days', true)));
console.log(Math.round(a.diff(b, 'hours', true)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Else is to force moment to use the utc date:

```js
const a = moment.utc(new Date('2021-10-31'));
const b = moment.utc(new Date('2021-11-01'));

console.log(a.diff(b, 'days'));
console.log(a.diff(b, 'hours'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'll file a bug report since your and my examples show stuff that can't be right.